# Salesforce1 Settings Need Managed Package Upgrade For Production Org

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, salesforce1-app

We have Managed package and have installed for many of our client in their production org.
Since salesforce1 in market clients asking for accessing our managed app from Salesforce1 application.

In our app we have overridden many tabs and standard buttons for the objects by VF. Now salesforce1 required visual force access set to true i.e. 'Available for Salesforce mobile apps' setting for VF for accessing through salesforce1.

Since we have managed package we will have to do changes in VF settings and  then deploy/upload changes for package into production org, that is the only way I have found.

Is there any alternative way?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was in the same situation a while back when I posted [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21768/how-does-salesforce-classify-an-app-as-salesforce1-ready) question. The short answer is that you should get in touch with your Salesforce Partner contact to have the required changes done to get your managed package listed as 'Salesforce1 Ready'.