# Need to create salesforce 1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app

I want to create a salesforce 1 App. How can i create it? I am not getting any option of creating salesforce 1 app.
Is there any option of creating app.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean by "create salesforce 1 app" and what result you are expecting ?

Comment: I mean, suppose I create 2-3 vf pages and lets say I give my App Name "Registration App". When user goes to Registration app, he will follow steps of registration via 2-3 vf pages.

Comment: Do i need to create app like the apps in Android, IOS or salesforce1 environment provides any option of creating an app.

Answer (score 1):

To see the new "salesforce 1" style UI, login to your org and enter /one/one.app (e.g. https://na15.salesforce.com/one/one.app). Essentially existing content is presented in a format more suitable for mobile devices and there is various additional configuration and programming you can do to make that mobile experience better still. A native app is provided for iOS and Android that just acts as the container for that (essentially HTML) content.

Comment: k. but how can i expose this app to the users so that they can download it and use it in their mobile phones. I also want to provide logo to my app. I want to create app just like apps created here https://appexchange.salesforce.com/collection/salesforce1-ready

Comment: @Pankaj You'll have to put your app through the normal AppExchange publishing processes; this includes things like a security review. See e.g. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21768/how-does-salesforce-classify-an-app-as-salesforce1-ready for some information about mobile specificically. Your question is too broad for this site's format; you'll have to do wider research yourself.